# Is it OK to copy DB files from one MySQL server to another?

Tags: mysql, database, file-transfer

I have two identically configured MySQL 5.6.10 servers and needed to move the data files fast from one to the other. Is this an OK procedure?
Here is what I did:
1) Shut down both servers
2) Moved all the files from one box to the other (DATA is on a separate drive on both machines)
3) Turned the second server on 
4) Connected it back to the app server
It took about 5 minutes to move all files (~50GB) and all seems to work. I just wonder if I missed anything?

Thanks much for your feedback.

Comment: If the version and config of the servers is exactly identical, things may work out. It's probably no best practice by any means, but I've had to resort to this a few times as well and haven't encountered any problems either. An additional precaution might be to bring down both MySQL processes before copying, while the 'right way' seems to be to use mysqldump and mysql command line tools (or some wrapping GUI) to export and import respectively.

Comment: You didn't miss anything. I've had to do this before for servers with 500GB+ of data with success. If the MySQL error log doesn't show anything significant, you're in the clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both the server versions are same, then I think, it's perfectly fine, not just OK, as I have done the same many times, without any data loss, but this method comes with cost:

1. You have to shut down mysql server (which is not good, if it's a production server)
2. You have to make sure the permission of data (mysql) directory is same as the previous one.
3. You will have to monitor the mysql_error log while starting the second server.

You can use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html), but if you don't want to, then you can use M[ysql Workbench's migration wizard](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/), it really takes care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

A much safer and recommended way would be [Database Backup And Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html).

Do a full backup from server1 and restore it to server2. Later then on, you can go for a differential backup.